# Python applying dynamic list comprehension (list append)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
vals= [1]
for j in xrange(i):
    vals.append([k for k in f(vals[j])])
```

This loop appends values to itself over a loop. If I compress this into a list comprehension, it doesn't work because it doesn't "dynamically" extend vals using itself on each iteration -- it processes vals as it is originally framed.

Is there a way to do a one line list comprehension that dynamically appends like this? Based on my research, it looks like maybe I am looking for a reduce function? (the equivalent of a fold)

Comment: You'll need to explain further. In the code as you show it, each execution of the list comprehension, ie on each iteration of `j`, will have a new value of `vals`.

Comment: What is `f` in `f(vals[j])`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Except it doesn't -- if you turn this into a list comprehension, it will give index errors once j>0

Comment: @MorganThrapp Arbitrary function

Comment: OK, I thought you were referring to the code as it was, and were having problems with the existing list comprehension. The answer then is no, and this code is fine as it is.

Comment: Are you using one of those nasty text editors that allow only so-and-so many lines per file or function? (Shorter is not always better)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm not referring to the code as it currently is (this code works), but I am trying to turn it into a one-liner

Comment: @tobias_k Similar to this, yes

Comment: This code will probably not behave usefully because you're modifying a list during iteration of it. Try running over a copy of vals, eg `f(vals[:][j])`. This could certainly be optimized further, but I don't know what behavior you're trying to express.

Comment: @Daenyth OP is not iterating over the list, but over a range. The loop should work fine.

Comment: what type should f return as its value?  I did f = lambda x: x which didnt work, could you also submit the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `reduce` for this, using the initial list as the third parameter.

```
>>> def f(lst):
...     return [x+1 for x in lst] + [len(lst)]
>>> reduce(lambda lst, i: lst + [f(lst[i])], range(5), [[1]])
[[1], [2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [4, 3, 3, 3], [5, 4, 4, 4, 4], [6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

(Note that the initial list should probably be `[[1]]`, not `[1]`, otherwise you are passing a number to `f` in the first iteration, but a list in all following iterations.)

Also note that concerning performance your original loop is probably a bit faster, as the `reduce` basically has to create two new lists in each iteration, while you just have to append to a list. Personally, I would go with a variation of the loop, removing the (probably useless) inner list comprehension and using `[-1]` to make clear that you are always using the previous result.

```
vals = [[1]]
for _ in xrange(n):
    vals.append(f(vals[-1]))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!